# Import Spark GraphFrame package into SparkR

Tags: apache-spark, sparkr, spark-graphx, graphframes

Is there any simple way to include and access GraphFrame in SparkR?

I have included the package as follows via cmd line:

`sparkr --packages graphframes:graphframes:0.2.0-spark2.0-s_2.10`, but cannot find documentation on how to use the package in SparkR.

Comment: Hi, does the above command fails to load the package in sparkR?

Comment: Currently there is no R support for graphframes. It's only available in Python and Scala.